# Couldn't connect the cluster from mongo shell due to "can’t connect to new replica set master" error

Tags: mongodb

How can I resolve this?

```
C:\Users\sivareddy>mongo “mongodb+srv://cluster0-ply0w.mongodb.net/mongo” --username sivareddy
    MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
    Enter password:
    connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017/mongo?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
    2020-05-06T12:23:56.912+0530 I NETWORK [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:23:56.919+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:23:56.920+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:23:56.920+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:23:58.947+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:23:59.447+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:24:00.447+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:24:00.947+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:24:00.948+0530 I CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:24:01.264+0530 I NETWORK [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for Cluster0-shard-0 is Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017
    2020-05-06T12:24:02.030+0530 I NETWORK [js] DBClientConnection failed to receive message from cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017 - SocketException: The specified data could not be decrypted.
    2020-05-06T12:24:02.030+0530 I NETWORK [js] Marking host cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location40659: can’t connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017], err: network error while attempting to run command ‘isMaster’ on host ‘cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017’

    *** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

    2020-05-06T12:24:02.032+0530 E QUERY [js] Error: can’t connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017], err: network error while attempting to run command ‘isMaster’ on host ‘cluster0-shard-00-01-ply0w.mongodb.net:27017’ :
    connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
    @(connect):2:6
    2020-05-06T12:24:02.037+0530 F - [main] exception: connect failed
    2020-05-06T12:24:02.037+0530 E - [main] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: `The specified data could not be decrypted` would seem to indicate a TLS problem.  Can your local machine validate the Atlas certificate?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).